# What is the standards-adherent content and format of an API's POST repsonse?

Tags: web-services, rest, http, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I am running a SPA with a server side web service.

That is my action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]CreateSchoolclassCodeRequestDto dto)
{
    await service.CreateSchoolclassCodeAsync(dto);
    return result;
}
```

What would standards-adherent result data look like?

- Just the `Id` of the created resource?
- The whole entity created by the `CreateSchoolClassCodeAsync`?
- A new Response object with the entity properties?

What `IActionResult` would be standards-adherent?

- `CreatedAtRouteResult`?
- `OkObjectResult`?
- `ObjectResult`?

Please include the specifications that explain the answer(s).

Comment: @close-voters, this question is not opinion-based, because the HTTP specs have clear guidance. This question is not off topic, because it is specifically asking about programming with ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How will your result data look like?

[Section 10 of RFC2616 states](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) that a successful POST response will include "an entity describing or containing the result of the action." In your case, the response can contain the actual result that the server created on receiving the POST.

> And what concrete `IActionResult` would you use?

ASP.NET Core MVC provides five viable alternatives. Your example does not make it clear which one to choose; so here are some guidelines.

[Section 9 of RFC2626](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) specifies three canonical responses to a successful POST and states that we should choose the most detailed one available. Here are the three from most to least detailed along with their ASP.NET Core MVC implementations.

**201 (Created) Response.** Use this if you can identify the result with a URI and can include an entity to describe the result. ASP.NET Core MVC provides three equivalent implementations:

- [`CreatedResult`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/CreatedResult.cs) to set the URI based on a string,
- [`CreatedAtActionResult`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/CreatedAtActionResult.cs) to set the URI based on an action, and
- [`CreatedAtRouteResult`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/CreatedAtRouteResult.cs) to set the URI based on a route.

**200 (OK) Response.** Use this if you can NOT identify the result with a URI but can include an entity to describe the result. ASP.NET Core MVC provides the [`OkObjectResult`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/OkObjectResult.cs).

**204 (No Content) Response.** Use this if you can NOT identify the result with a URI and can NOT include an entity to describe the result. ASP.NET Core MVC provides the [`NoContentResult`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/NoContentResult.cs).

Comment: Is an id really an entity? Because the result must be an entity. Together with the Id I use the OkObjectResult. Thanks for your answer like it. Although I must admin my question seemed partly opiniated based.

Comment: @pascal Good comment. Updated.